# HTML5 Canvas Hide and show specific image

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have one canvas. In this canvas I have an image who cover the whole of my canvas ( this is an image of a tablet ). In this image I have 3 little image and I have 3 buttons.

How can I do, when I click on the first button this make my first image hidden or visible ? And do it the same thing for the other buttons.

**Update**

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om5cogu6/). I created 3 buttons :

1. The Twitter button to Show / Hide the twitter icon.
2. The Facebook button to toggle it with [Google Chrome icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).png).
3. The Linkedin button to show / hide the linkedin icon.

   ```
   var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   var tablet = loadImage('http://pngimg.com/upload/tablet_PNG8592.png', main);
   var twitter = loadImage('http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/f/f3/Twitter_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20120120012303', main);
   var facebook = loadImage('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/512/social-facebook-box-blue-icon.png', main);
   var linkedin = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Linkedin_Shiny_Icon.svg/1000px-Linkedin_Shiny_Icon.svg.png', main);

   var imagesLoaded = 0;

   function main() {
     imagesLoaded += 1;

     if(imagesLoaded == 4) {
      // Tablet pic
      ctx.drawImage(tablet, 0, 0, 850, 450);

      // Twitter Pic
      ctx.drawImage(twitter, 150, 120, 150, 150);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Twitter", 200, 300);

      // Facebook Pic
      ctx.drawImage(facebook, 335, 120, 150, 150);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Facebook", 365, 300);

      // Linkedin Pic
      ctx.drawImage(linkedin, 540, 120, 150, 150);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Linkedin", 580, 300);
    }
   }

   function loadImage(src, onload) {
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = onload;
      img.src = src;

      return img;
   }
   ```

**UPDATE 2**

I made another [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/om5cogu6/2/). Now we can click on the facebook button and this goggle with the linkedin picture. But I have a problem about the clearRect. After the clearRect we can see the canvas background color. I can't clearRect with a rounded border.

How can I do this ?

Comment: This might be a good question. I would suggest you add your code so that we know what we're looking at.

Comment: Yes tomorrow ill update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Now I can toggle 2 images. I worked during a long night and I developed this : [See my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om5cogu6/3/)

As you can see I developed 3 functions :

1. clearArea() : To clear the picture, the text area and draw a rect with the same color of the tablet background.
2. add_image() : Add your image to the canvas (need to be loaded before).
3. add_text() : This function add a text under the pictures or whatever you want.

And for the toggle this is in the Facebook click event.

```
// Clear the area 
function clearArea(clear_position, color){

  // Clear area
  ctx.clearRect(clear_position[0], clear_position[1], clear_position[2], clear_position[3]);

  // Recover the background color
  ctx.fillStyle = color;

  // Draw the background
  ctx.fillRect(clear_position[0], clear_position[1], clear_position[2], clear_position[3]);

}

// Add an image to the context
function add_image(image, image_size){

  // Draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(image, image_size[0], image_size[1], image_size[2], image_size[3]);

}

// Add a text to the context
function add_text(text_color, text_font, text_value, text_position){

  // Text color
  ctx.fillStyle = text_color;

  // Font type and size
  ctx.font = text_font;

  // Text value and position
  ctx.fillText(text_value, text_position[0], text_position[1]);

}


$('#toggle_facebook').on('click', function(){


if (icon_facebook_count++ % 2 != 0) {

  clearArea( [335, 120, 150, 190], '#272727');

  add_image( facebook, [335, 120, 150, 150] );

  add_text( 'white', text_size, 'Facebook', [370, 300] );

}else{

  clearArea( [335, 120, 150, 190], '#272727');

  add_image( googlechrome, [335, 120, 150, 150] );

  add_text( 'white', text_size, 'Google', [377, 300] );

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As par tutorial given [here](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/html-5-tutorials/html-5-canvas). you can show custom image using following code

```
<img id="scream" src="/examples/example.png" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<p><button onclick="mycanvas()">Try it</button></p>

<script>
function mycanvas() {
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
</script>
```

You can add some javascript logic to show hide as par your requirements. Here is a working [example](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/html-5-tutorials/try-it-yourself/draw-image).